# User not serialized when using async auth route and passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, asynchronous, express

I've got a node app that operates in isolation. Without js on in the client it just operates synchronously, setting cookies with passport.js. When the client is js enabled then the auth is done via a rest route.

All seems fine, except that if I have authenticated (and have cookies set) asynchronously, but then refresh the page (or navigate synchronously to a new one [for whatever reason]), the server sends the response with new cookies that overwrite the old ones and setting the user back to being unauthenticated.

```
    // =============================================================================
// AUTHENTICATE (FIRST LOGIN) ==================================================
// =============================================================================

// process the login form
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect: '/browse?p=0', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
}));


app.post('/async/login', function(req, res, next) {

    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info, status) {

        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }

        if (user) {
            user.local = null;
            return res.send(user);

        } else {
            return res.send(info);
        }

    })(req, res, next);


});


 // =========================================================================
// passport session setup ==================================================
// =========================================================================
// required for persistent login sessions
// passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

// =========================================================================
// LOCAL LOGIN =============================================================
// =========================================================================
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass in the req from our route (lets us check if a user is logged in or not)
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        // asynchronous
        process.nextTick(function() {
            User.findOne({
                'local.email': email
            }).populate({
                path: 'spots comments currentLocation'
            }).exec(function(err, user) {
                // if there are any errors, return the error
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                // if no user is found, return the message
                if (!user)
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));

                if (!user.validPassword(password))
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));

                // all is well, return user
                else

                    User.populate(user, {
                    path: 'spots.bird',
                    model: 'Bird'
                }, function(err, user) {

                    if (err)
                        return done(err);

                    else

                        User.populate(user, {
                        path: 'spots.location',
                        model: 'Location'
                    }, function(err, user) {
                        if (err)
                            return done(err);
                        else
                            console.log(util.inspect(user, showHidden = false, depth = 5, colorize = true));
                        return done(null, user);
                    });
                });

            });
        });

    }));
```

Node App:

```
app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(cookieParser());


sessionVars = {
    keys: ['<removed>'],
    //secureProxy: true, // if you do SSL outside of node
    maxAge: 2592000000
};

app.use(session(sessionVars));

app.use(flash());

require('./../modules/auth/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Does anyone know why?

UPDATE: The async route doesn't seem to call the serializeUser function (which explains everything!). Does anyone know how to force serialization?

If I try a direct call: passport.serializeUser(user, done) then I need the done parameter, which isn't available in the routes file (although I could pass it through);

Does anybody know if serializeUser is meant to be called as a matter of course with passport strategies?

Comment: Could it be related to `saveUninitialized` or `resave` options from [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) ? Check the docs regarding these parameters, try setting them to false to see if something changes.

Comment: Thanks @WaldoJeffers. I've had a play around with those and it seems not... but great suggestion though! :)

Answer (score 1):

So I found that if you use the custom form of the authenticate function:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
 passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
          return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

it doesn't seem to pass it through the serializeUser function that you provide. The cookies for sessions stay in your browser and change all the time, even when you're logged out as they probably still 'tracking' your behaviour.

If you use the 'black box' version of the function:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                               failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

that works because it calls serializeUser automatically.